# Internet works only with Tor Browser nothing else (Mozilla, other apps) using Windows

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, firefox

I installed Tor Browser a week ago.
I use it first and when I can't go on specific websites, I use Firefox.
I also have other apps and software using internet on my computer.
Since 2 days, now, for no apparent reasons, I haven't changed anything, I can access Internet only through Tor Browser. Nothing else is working.
All the other browsers, apps, software ask me to connect my computer to Internet.

Can someone help me by telling me how can I fix that?
Thanks

Comment: You should try asking somewhere like the SuperUser stack exchange, they might be able to help. This sounds like it may be a problem with your DNS settings.

Comment: Did you modify any network settings since installation, any at all?

Comment: I am also having this strange issue. and no, no network setting have been modified at all.